# From single array convert to an array of object with keys coming from a JSON response -JAVASCRIPT-

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, reduce

I am receiving a json response from an API call. I need to store its keys, and create an array of an object. I am intending to this array of an object is created dynamically no matter the keys of the response.

I've already got the keys like this:

```
  const json_getAllKeys = data => {
   const keys = data.reduce((keys, obj) => (
      keys.concat(Object.keys(obj).filter(key => (
        keys.indexOf(key) === -1))
      )
    ), [])
    return keys 
}
```

That returned an array (using a sample json):

```
['name','username', 'email']
```

But I am trying to use that array to create an array of object that looks like this one

```
[
    {
      name: "name",
      username: "username",
      email: "Email",
    }
];
```

I've been trying mapping the array, but got multiple objects because of the loop, and I need a single one to make it work.

```
keys.map(i=>({i:i}))

[
  { i: 'id' },
  { i: 'name' },
  { i: 'username' },
  { i: 'email' }
]
```

Any hint would be useful!

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: yes exactly, no way to do that?

Comment: there is many, but I don't understand how is your original data

Comment: original data comes from a json. From there I got an array with the keys of that response!

Comment: you mean `data = ['name','username', 'email']` ?  or `keys = ['name','username', 'email']` (returned and in this case what is the value of data) ? this is unclear

Comment: your code on `data.reduce((keys, obj)` is wrong, Array.reduce() work in an other way, it use accumulator

Comment: keys come from the response, ['name','username', 'email'] are they keys of the json. The value is random data from JSONPlaceholder. My apologies if it  sounds confusing, I am trying to explain myself as good as I can.

Comment: I don't ask for the value of keys, I  ask for the value of data, `const json_getAllKeys = data =>...`  this **data**

Comment: Data is the json itself. Thanks for your time and good intentions to help!

Comment: As I wrote before your code on `data.reduce((keys, obj)` is wrong

Comment: I know, now I see, thanks for making me notice that. I still struggle using reduce() efficiently. I'm correcting it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), which is ECMA2019, I believe, so available in Node >=14 and will be provided as a polyfill if you employ [babel](https://babeljs.io/).

I can't quite discern what your `reduce` should produce, but given the sample input, I would write

```js
const input = ['name','username', 'email'];

const result = Object.fromEntries(input.map(name => ([name, name])));
// result == { name: 'name', username: 'username', email: 'email' }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely on the right track. One thing to remember is the map function will return the SAME number of output as input. So in your example, an array of 3 returns an array of 3 items.

For this reason, map alone is not going to give you what you want. You may be able to map => reduce it. However, here is a way using forEach instead. This isn't a strictly functional programming style solution, but is pretty straight forward and depending on use case, probably good enough.

```
let keys = ['name','username', 'email'] //you have this array
const obj = {}; // empty object to hold result
keys.forEach(i => {
    obj[i] = i;  // set the object as you want
})

console.log(obj); // log out the mutated object
// { name: 'name', username: 'username', email: 'email' }
```

Comment: Leaving this here because it is a solution. Overall though I think John's answer is 'better'.